# How to connect points in python ax.scatter 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter3d

I have a 3D plot in python which I made using `ax.scatter(x,y,z,c='r',s=100)`
from the

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pylab

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D.
```

I want to connect my points with a line. I know you can do it with `marker='-o'` but that works only in 2D for me and not 3D. Can anyone help ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Please take the  [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scatter does not allow for connecting points. The argument `marker='-o'` only works for `plot`, not for `scatter`. That is true for 2D and 3D. But of course you can use a scatter **and** a plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

ax = plt.gca(projection="3d")
x,y,z = [1,1.5,3],[1,2.4,3],[3.4,1.4,1]
ax.scatter(x,y,z, c='r',s=100)
ax.plot(x,y,z, color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It *is* clear: they were trying to use `scatter`, not `plot`. I don't think both telling off askers for asking an ill-formed question *and* giving them an answer is helpful.

Comment: Yes I am trying to use scatter and then connect my points. I am sorry for asking the question wrong, but I am a physicist who is not very good at programming and I have to finish the asignement by tommorow so I am in a bit of a hurry.

Comment: Scatter does not allow for connecting points. That is true for 2D and 3D. But of course you can use a `scatter` **and** a `plot`.